# Disabled auto negotiation on both sides but one side is 10Mbps/Full Duplex and other side is 100Mbps/Full duplex. what happens?

Tags: ethernet

On PC side with windows xp, i have selected 10Mbps full duplex mode in the driver. I connect this Ethernet cable of PC to my development board(DM6446) which has 100Mbps full duplex mode. What happens in this scenario?

Regards

Comment: IT depends on if the DM6446 will auto negotiate or not. If it does then it drop its own speed to match that of the XP machines NIC if its doesn't then it most likely will show connected by not be able to transfer any traffic successfully or at best have a very poor packet success rate.

Answer (score 0):

"Nothing"

Both sides are forced to incompatible speeds, no link will be formed.

Comment: I transfer an image via UDP from one side to other, then image gets transferred. But If we start to do image transfer from both the sides(PC and DM6446), then there is a packet drop.

Comment: Then the DM isn't forced to 100/Full; it's auto-sensing, but without auto-negotiation it will not be full duplex. So, you have a duplex mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that one or other of the ends implements parallel detection (sometimes called autosense). The signal received is passed to both the 10BASE-T decoder and the 100BASE-TX decoder, and if it (say) makes sense as 100BASE-TX may override the configured speed. If it strictly followed the standard then the link wouldn't have come up at all.

I'm mildly surprised that this happened with a fixed speed settings, rather than a fallback after autonegotiation failed.

However, unlike autonegotiate parallel detection can't determine the correct duplex settings, and falls back to half-duplex. So either the XP box flipped to 100Mbps half-duplex or the DM6446 flipped to 10Mbps half-duplex.

Comment: Your answer is a bit hard to understand as written. Can you explain what this "parallel detection" or "autosense" is in more detail?